# Spring HATEOAS and mockMVC, ignores consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE

Tags: json, spring, hateoas, mockmvc, hal

After creating a service using Spring HATEOAS and testing it with mockmvc (also to generate documentation using Spring restdocs) we found the following.

Our RestController looks something like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/my")
@ExposesResourceFor(My.class)
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class MyController {

   @Autowired
   private MyRepository myRepository;

   @Autowired
   private MyResourceAssembler myResourceAssembler;

   @RequestMapping(path = "", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
   public HttpEntity<Resource<MyResource>> addMy(
        @RequestBody MyResource newMyResource) {

    if (myRepository.existsByMyId(newMyResource.getMyId())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    val newMy = new My(
            null, // generates id
            newMy.getMyId()
    );

    val myResource = myResourceAssembler.toResource(myRepository.save(newMy));
    val resource = new Resource<>(myResource);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }
}
```

To test this we have created the following test:

```
@Test
public void addMy() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/my")
            .content("{ \"myId\": 9911 }")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .accept(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.myId").value(9911))   
            .andDo(this.document.document(selfLinkSnippet, responseFieldsSnippet));
}
```

The unit test result we get is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :201
Actual   :415
```

Status code 415 is Media Type unsupported.

If we modify the unit test to say:

```
.contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)
```

The unit test returns success. Which is strange since we indicated to consume only application/json. 
The problem now is that the documentation that is generated, incorrectly states that the POST request should use Content-type application/hal+json:

```
curl 'http://my-service/v1/my' -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/hal+json' -H 'Accept: application/hal+json' -d '{ "myId": 9911 }'
```

And if you try that, you will get another 415.
If we change the Content-Type: to application/json, then it does work.

If we tell the method to consume both HAL+JSON and JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = POST, consumes = { MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
```

Then the unit test succeeds when contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON) is set, but fails when contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8) is set.

However, now the service both accepts application/json AND application/hal+json, such that the documentation is at least working.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I found another stackoverflow question: [Spring MVC controller ignores "consumes" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239072/spring-mvc-controller-ignores-consumes-property)

And the solution there worked for me as well. I added the @EnableWebMvc to the test configuration class.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({CommonTestConfiguration.class})
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class MyControllerTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyRepository myRepository() {

        return new InMemoryMyRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyController myController() {
        return new MyController();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyResourceAssembler myResourceAssembler() {
        return new myResourceAssembler();
    }
}
```